# The type name 'Models' does not exist in the type 'Database'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I tried to create a really simple dbcontext class today with 2 classes "Class" and "Student". After I enabled-migrations the configuration file keeps saying it connot find the namespace to Models in the project Database.

ERROR CODE:
CS0426  The type name 'Models' does not exist in the type 'Database'    Database    C:\Users\rodney\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SchoolManagementProtal\Database\Migrations\Configuration.cs

Project stucture
[image]

DbContext class:

```
using  System.Data.Entity;

namespace Database.Models
{
    public class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Class>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Students)
                .WithMany(c => c.Classes);


        }
    }
}
```

Configuration file in migrations:

```
namespace Database.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Database.**Models**.DbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }


    }
}
```

Class Entity:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Database.Models
{
    public class Class
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ClassName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1, 100)]
        public int MaxStudents { get; set; }

        public int StudentId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Students Entity

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Database.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ClassId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int TotalHours { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int HoursStudied { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateJoined { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }


        public int HoursLeft
        {
            get
            {
                return this.TotalHours - this.HoursStudied;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I guess I am missing some type of reference or something. but even after googling for some time I couldn't find any solution. Thanks for the help in advance. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a name clash between [`System.Data.Entity.Database`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database(v=vs.113).aspx) **class** and your `Database` **namespace**, in which case the class takes precedence, hence the compiler error.

You need to resolve it by either using the global namespace alias:

```
: DbMigrationsConfiguration<global::Database.Models.DbContext>
```

or since in this particular case the `Database.Models` is directly accessible from `Database.Migrations`, by using relative namespace reference:

```
: DbMigrationsConfiguration<Models.DbContext>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer as well as the clear explanation.